# Problem with chordbox and sharps

Tags: tikz-pgf

I encountered another `chordbox` issue that occurs when the tuning defined contains a sharp (or a flat). In the example given below, I defined *open G* as the tuning, but with a *capo on the 4th fret*. With a capo on the 4th fret, the tuning with respect to open G is *F#-B-F#-B-D#-F#*. When I compile the document, I get, in the output, two sharps for those notes which come after a sharp defined at the fretboard nut. For example, the note that follows a D# should be an E, but it is an #D# in the output. Unfortunately, I am not really familiar with the nuts and bolts of TiKZ and cannot fix the problem on my own, but I suppose there might be something wrong in the for loops or if statements defined in `chordbox`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
\usepackage{chordbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red}%

\pgfkeys{%
/chordbox/text on node=pitch,%
/chordbox/numfrets=6,%
/chordbox/text below=pitch,%
/chordbox/text on node =pitch,%
/chordbox/tuning={"F\#","B","F\#","B","D\#","F\#"}%
}%
\tikzset{%
chordbox/.append style={scale=2.5,thick},%
string/muted/.style={string/open,cross out,minimum size=12}%
}%    
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}%

\begin{document}

\section{Open G tuning}

With a \textit{capo} on the \textit{4th fret}, the tuning is
F$\sharp$, B, F$\sharp$, B, D$\sharp$, F$\sharp$, which actually is \textit{open B}.

\begin{itemize}
  \item Chordbox~\ref{fig:b_chord} is correct.

  \item In chordbox~\ref{fig:b6sus4_chord}, \#G should be G$\sharp$,
        and \#D$\sharp$ should be E.

  \item In chordbox~\ref{fig:e_chord},  x, E, \#A$\sharp$, E, \#G, \#A$\sharp$
        should be x, E, B, E, G$\sharp$, B.

  \item In chordbox~\ref{fig:e6sus4_chord}, \#A$\sharp$ should be B,
        \#G$\sharp$ should be A, \#C$\sharp$ should be C$\sharp$.

  \item In chordbox~\ref{fig:e_over_b_chord}, \#A$\sharp$ should be B.
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\subfloat[B Major][B Major]
{\chordbox{B}{x,0,0,0,0,0}\label{fig:b_chord}}
\subfloat[B6sus4][B6sus4]
{\chordbox{B6sus4}{x,0,2,0,1,0}\label{fig:b6sus4_chord}}
\subfloat[E Major][E Major]
{\chordbox{E}{x,5,5,5,5,5}\label{fig:e_chord}}
\qquad
\subfloat[E6sus4][E6sus4]
{\bchordbox[5]{E6sus4}{x,5,7,5,6,5}{5}\label{fig:e6sus4_chord}}
\subfloat[E5/B chord][E5/B]
{\chordbox{E5/B}{x,x,5,5,x,x}\label{fig:e_over_b_chord}}
\caption{Several open G chords (capo on 4th fret)}
\label{fig:globfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: PDF outpt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package uses an `\if` test to match the tuning list to the entry in the pitch list that needs to be used for printing the node. This does not work when the tuning list contains macros such as `\#`.

Instead you can use `\IfStrEq` from the `xstring` package to do the string matching. `xstring` is already used by `chordbox` so it makes sense to do the check also with that package.

The code that needs to be redefined is the handler `@typeset pitch`. The redefinition can be done using a `\pgfqkeys` statement after loading the package.

Relevant code from the preamble:

```
\usepackage{chordbox}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/chordbox}{
    @typeset pitch/.code 2 args={%
        \pgfmathparse{{\cb@tuning}[#1-1]}%
        \ifnum#2=0%
            \pgfkeys{@replace symbols=\pgfmathresult}%
        \else%
            \foreach \p in {0,...,11} {%
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\stringpitch}{{\cb@pitchnames}[\p]}%
                \IfStrEq{\stringpitch}{\pgfmathresult}{%
                    \pgfmathparse{{\cb@pitchnames}[mod(\p + #2, 12)]}%
                    \pgfkeys{@replace symbols=\pgfmathresult}%
                    \breakforeach%
                }{}%
            }%
        \fi%
    }
}
\makeatother
```

Result:

[image]